# VSCode Java Extension: how to kill Java Build Status task (frozen at 5%)

Tags: java, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to build a good development environment for work that uses VSCode to work with our EE Java stuff. I've been having a liteny of issues attempting to get newly added imports in a pom.xml to be reflected in the editor. I figured a good way to force it would be to right click a java project and hit "Update project", but that freezes at 5%.
[image]

A few things:

1. The Java log doesn't show anything (is there a verbose options I cant find?)
2. I can't terminate the task. Terminating the window doesn't stop the process. (restarting Vscode is getting annoying)
3. I am using version 1.4.0 Java extension by Red Hat

Does anyone know how to solve point 2 at least? allowing me to actually cancel the task and iteratively try new things instead of closing everything down each time? And if some even kinder soul knows how to fix the 5% issue generally I wouldn't turn down that information either.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a solution by now? I'm also trying to get vscode to work with an enterprise Spring Boot application and I got the same error. Also using the Java Language Support by Red Hat

Comment: @ch1ll. At some point upgrading the JAVA package I used for VSCode got this to work. Unfortunately my work ended up clamping down on my vscode useage so now i'm on Eclipse. Sorry for the far too late answer.

Comment: I also convinced our team to switch to intelliJ by now :D